# Weird lines are appearing on shut down

Tags: shutdown

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 because Windows has gone wrong. From the first time I shut Ubuntu down weird text had been appearing then the screen goes off-then shuts down.

Is there any way to get my computer to say `Shutting Down Ubuntu` (Or something like that) when I shut down without using terminal to get it to do this?

The only reason I don't want to use terminal is because I'm new to Ubuntu and I don't want to do something wrong and not not be able log on or something.

Comment: what you see should mostly be feedback that programs are getting closed. I don't see the problem: can't you ignore it or does it take an uncommonly long time until it is shut down? Also if you want to shutdown in terminal, you can use `sudo poweroff`.

Comment: Windows went wrong when it was released :)
As @user42257 said, it basically shows the processes being stopped, which I don't think is a bad thing at all. Considering how rarely I reboot my system given how stable Ubuntu is, I don't care about startup/shutdown appearances